# Calculate working hours monthly. MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I need to calculate the total working time from a single table. My problem is the working time sometimes elapse over the month end and I need the working hours for each month.
Here is some example data:

> ```
> StartTime    EndTime      Staff 
> 3/31 16:50  3/31 19:30      B 
> 3/31 23:10  4/1  01:30      B 
> 4/1  01:40  4/1 03:55       B
> ```

The result should be

```
Month   Staff      WorkingHours
March     B            3:30
April     B            1:30
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this problem there are two kinds of records:

1. records where the [StartTime] and [StopTime] are in the same month, and
2. records where they are not.

Calculating the elapsed times for the first case is easy:

```
SELECT 
    Staff, 
    Month([StartTime]) AS WorkMonth,
    DateDiff("n", [StartTime], [EndTime]) AS MinutesWorked
FROM WorkLog
WHERE Month([EndTime])=Month([StartTime])
```

Calculating the elapsed time for the records that span a month boundary is a two-part process:

(i) Get the elapsed time for the earlier month

```
SELECT 
    Staff, 
    Month([StartTime]) AS WorkMonth,
    DateDiff("n", [StartTime], DateSerial(Year([StartTime]), Month([StartTime]) + 1, 1)) AS MinutesWorked
FROM WorkLog
WHERE Month([EndTime])>Month([StartTime])
```

(ii) Get the elapsed time for the following month

```
SELECT 
    Staff, 
    Month([EndTime]) AS WorkMonth,
    DateDiff("n", DateSerial(Year([EndTime]), Month([EndTime]), 1), [EndTime]) AS MinutesWorked
FROM WorkLog
WHERE Month([EndTime])>Month([StartTime])
```

So, to get the totals we just UNION ALL the three queries and wrap them in an aggregation query to perform the SUM()

```
SELECT WorkMonth, Staff, SUM(MinutesWorked) AS TotalMinutes
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Staff, 
            Month([StartTime]) AS WorkMonth,
            DateDiff("n", [StartTime], [EndTime]) AS MinutesWorked
        FROM WorkLog
        WHERE Month([EndTime])=Month([StartTime])
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            Staff, 
            Month([StartTime]) AS WorkMonth,
            DateDiff("n", [StartTime], DateSerial(Year([StartTime]), Month([StartTime]) + 1, 1)) AS MinutesWorked
        FROM WorkLog
        WHERE Month([EndTime])>Month([StartTime])
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            Staff, 
            Month([EndTime]) AS WorkMonth,
            DateDiff("n", DateSerial(Year([EndTime]), Month([EndTime]), 1), [EndTime]) AS MinutesWorked
        FROM WorkLog
        WHERE Month([EndTime])>Month([StartTime])
    )
GROUP BY WorkMonth, Staff
```

That will return...

```
WorkMonth  Staff  TotalMinutes
---------  -----  ------------
        3  B               210
        4  B               225
```

...and you can add `Format()` functions if you want to tweak the formatting of the Month (e.g., as text) or the total time (e.g. as "hh:nn").

Comment: +1 Because using SQL is always preferable over going through recordsets.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into a logic statement using [datediff() from here.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx)  It allows you to easily subtract months, days, hours, etc.

If you were to add in an initial `If-Else` asking:

```
If DateDiff("m", #Date1#, #Date2#) = 0 Then

    'The times here would be in the same month

Else

    `The times here would split months

End If
```

And if you don't want to use a logic statement in VBA, you can also run a DateDiff() query.

I'm not sure how many records you are dealing with here, so looping through each record if you have 10s of 1000s may not be the most efficient, but it would get the job done.  If you're unfamiliar with the VBA approach I would be happy to modify my existing `If-Else` with a little more data to point you in the right direction.